# With Elixir Ecto, how do I add a has_many relationship in a migration?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to write something like this:

```
defmodule JobHunt.Repo.Migrations.CompaniesHaveManyJobs do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table (:companies) do
      add :jobs, :has_many, Job
    end
  end
end
```

Running `mix ecto.migrate` with this migration gives an error, so what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should add the required foreign key to the jobs table:

```
defmodule JobHunt.Repo.Migrations.CompaniesHaveManyJobs do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:jobs) do
      add :company_id, :integer
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Good point. That updates the database. To make it accessible from Ecto, I  added `belongs_to :company, JobHunt.Company` to the schema section in `web/models/job.ex`.

Comment: @Jose Why is it :integer instead of `references(:comapnies)`?
Is there any noticeable difference to it?

Comment: Using references is better, yes.

Answer (score 15):

Or you could use [`Ecto.Migration.references/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto_sql/Ecto.Migration.html#references/2), as the documentation recommends:

```
alter table(:jobs) do
  add :company_id, references(:companies)
end
```

I'm not sure whether the plural version is required here: `references(:companies)` but it did not work for me with `pharmacy` (singular)

Comment: Regarding your question, I believe it's plural because you're referencing the database table rather than the Ecto schema or Phoenix context.